# Placeholder appearing only after click HTML JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple form. When the page loads, the input fields are empty, and the placeholder only appears when I click on the field.

```
<input type="text" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Vorname,  
 Name';"     onfocus="if(this.value=='Vorname, Name')     
this.value='';"         name="dynamic_0" title="Vorname, Name" value="">
```

How can I get the placeholder to be visible on page load as well?

Comment: use the property placeholder to set a placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

Use the html placeholder element

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="whatever you want" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Vorname, Name';"     onfocus="if(this.value=='Vorname, Name') this.value='';"         name="dynamic_0" title="Vorname, Name" value="">
```

for old IE compatibility you should check out this polyfill aswell:
https://github.com/ginader/HTML5-placeholder-polyfill